# Allow limited number of possibilities for a option in boost program_options

Tags: boost, boost-program-options

Can I tell boost program_options somehow, that a specific options has a limited number of values?
For example, the option "--verbosity" may only be debug,high or low?!?

Thanks!
Nathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation explains how to write [Custom Validators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#id1421830).